# How does the C++ linker know which .lib contains which functions?

Tags: c++, boost, linker

For example in Boost. I set an *include* directory in MSVC++2010 to the Boost root directory and have an `#include <boost/regex.hpp>` in my source code. I set a *library* directory to `boost\stage\lib` but there are hundreds of files in there – several for each Boost library and these for boost::regex:

```
libboost_regex-vc100-s-1_46.lib
libboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_46.lib
libboost_regex-vc100-mt-1_46.lib
libboost_regex-vc100-mt-s-1_46.lib
libboost_regex-vc100-mt-s.lib
libboost_regex-vc100-s.lib
libboost_regex-vc100-mt.lib
libboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd.lib
```

How does MSVC know which of all lib files is the right one? If it scans all of them for the right function signatures, does that mean that 2 different lib's compiled from two different sources (not linked to each other) which happen to define functions with identical names and parameters cannot be in one lib folder?

And how does it know which is right among all those different regex .lib's? And then, each file with `1_46` in its filename seems to be identical to the respective file without, can I safely delete one of the two?

Comment: I bet that if you look inside `regex.hpp`, you'll find dozens of `#pragma library` statements (or similar. I forget the exact syntax)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The boost libraries use some *dark magic* to select the libraries to link from the headers and compiler options. I don't really know all the gory details, but you can take a look at the boost/config/auto_link.hpp header for extra information.

In particular, this seems to be an important piece of the puzzle:

```
#  pragma comment(lib, BOOST_LIB_PREFIX BOOST_STRINGIZE(BOOST_LIB_NAME) "-" BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET BOOST_LIB_THREAD_OPT BOOST_LIB_RT_OPT "-" BOOST_LIB_VERSION ".lib")
```

Comment: Hm, nice. I only wonder why they wouldn't include their "address-type" (32/64 bits) in the name. To have a module compile in both versions is still some manual work because the library paths cannot be the default (boost\stage\lib) for both.

Answer (score 6):

Most `lib` files have a Table Of Contents.   The linker searches this table when it is looking for a symbol.  If the symbol is not found it moves on to the next library, and so on, until all libraries have been searched.

Some linkers may decide to build a table of contents from all the libraries.  This table would contain the symbol name and the library it is associated with.  This speeds up the searches for symbols.

The search order depends on the manufacturer of the linker.  There is no standard nor requirements for this.  A linker may search by *first come, first served* as specified on the command line; *last library specified* or some other method.  Check the documentation for the criteria.

Also search the web for `name mangling`.  This is a technique that compilers use to resolve symbol naming conflicts.

Lastly, linkers may include all the functions in a library even if only one is used.  Some linkers only include the code for the function.  Depends on the manufacturer of the Linker.  For example, does the linker include the entire I/O library when resolving `puts` or does it just include the necessary functions?  Including the whole library speeds up build time but makes the executable huge.  Including only necessary code slows the build process but shrinks the executable size.

In general, the Linking Phase is one of the faster parts of the translation process.  If you are worried about build times, start the build at the end of the day or go for a walk after the build is started. ;-)

Comment: This explains how linkers work in general, but it doesn't answer the question. Boost magically links with _the right_ lib file without the programmer specifying it, but how?

Answer (score 2):

Two libraries containing identical functions isn't a problem. The linker only looks at the libraries that it's told to look at. If two of *them* contain identical functions, it'll give an error message (this is actually fairly common, usually due to conflict between static and dynamic linking with the standard library).

You can tell the linker which libraries to look at in a number of ways -- on the linker command line (possibly as generated by the IDE) and via `#pragma comment(lib, "libname.lib")` are the two most common though.

Comment: Almost true Jerry.  It is perfectly valid to have two identically-named functions in two libraries which are both linked in.  I do this to have my own implementations of malloc, free, ...  But (a big but) is that you must be sure to overrule ALL external symbols from the second definition in the libraries.  Once the linker has resolved a symbol name, it simply won't look for a second occurance of the symbol.